# C# ProgressBar not showing progress in media player

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp-xaml

everyone. I've encountered a problem while developing my test media player in C#. I think I put all the code, but when I open file, it starts playing but progress bar isn't moving. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Media;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;


namespace App1

{


public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick +=  timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();

    }
    TimeSpan _position;

    private async void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();

        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;

        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");

        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");

        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
        var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null)

        {

            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);


            videoMediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);


        }
    }

    private void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(videoMediaElement.PlaybackRate != 1 )
        {
            videoMediaElement.DefaultPlaybackRate = 1;

        }

        videoMediaElement.Play();

    }

    private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoMediaElement.Stop();
    }

    private void ProgressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (videoMediaElement.Source != null && videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
        {
           ProgressBar.Minimum =  0;
           ProgressBar.Maximum = videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
           ProgressBar.Value = videoMediaElement.Position.TotalSeconds;
        }
    }

    private void videoMediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _position = videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
        ProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
        ProgressBar.Maximum = _position.TotalSeconds;
    }
}
}
```

and XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button x:Name="Open" Content="Open" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,564,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="299" Click="Open_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="Play" Content="Play" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="393,564,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="299" Click="Play_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="Stop" Content="Stop" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="737,564,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="299" Click="Stop_Click"/>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" 

                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" Margin="60,665,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1185" ValueChanged="ProgressBar_ValueChanged"/>
    <Slider x:Name="slider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1082,557,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="videoMediaElement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="491.884" Margin="4.22,58.023,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1270.501" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" MediaOpened="videoMediaElement_MediaOpened">
        <MediaElement.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="0.111"/>
        </MediaElement.RenderTransform>
    </MediaElement>

</Grid>
```

PLZ HELP!! I wasted 2 days and I found no real solution on google. Thank you!

Comment: Have you debugged your `timer_Tick` event to check the value of `TotalSeconds`?

Comment: yeah. debugger showed no errors.. I dont know what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I looked at your code and found your problem. It appears that SetSource() method doesn't really set mediaelement's source. I have no idea why. Maybe someone here will help you with that. There are several things that I can point out.

1. You start filling this progressbar before the movie starts. Which is a problem. You could initialize your timer not in MainPage constructor but in your Play_Click event or in this case where your movie starts automatically in you Open_Click event.
2. As I mentioned since the source is always null the progressbar will never fill. Fortunately there is a way to check if video element is currently running. Replace this:

   if (videoMediaElement.Source != null && videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)

With This:

```
if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. ProgressBar is now loading as it should. But another 2 question got on my mind: 1. What do you mean about SetSource() method? 2. If I initialize timer in Play_Click event, will it star 2 timers or it will automatically be set on 1 timer? Anyway, I would buy you a beer if you were near me.

Comment: You are using SetSource to load file in your mediaelement. But this does not set your source property which you are checking for null. About the timer. It wont be initialized twice if you only initialize there. If my answer helped you just mark it as correct, after all this is the pourpose of SO. :)